# Шестигранник с закругленными углами - максимально просто

Tags: html, css, svg

Какой лучший способ для создания изображения шестигранника с тенью?

> https://codepen.io/Zentro/project/editor/AaoveW/

`- версия с svg-фильтром`.

1. Я пробовал вставить картинку - тогда нельзя применить тень.
2. Сделал с помощью `css/html`(трансформированные дивы - 3 шт) - нельзя закруглить углы.
3. Сделал с помощью `svg-filter`, но и тут беда - в хроме иногда пропадают картинки.

Подскажите как это сделать правильно и максимально просто?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### SVG решение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Шестиугольник выступает в роли маски.
2. Маска задана в секции `<defs>`
3. Далее она накладывается на изображение, что остается за границами
   маски обрезается.
4. Ширина границы маски-шестиугольника задается атрибутом -
   `stroke-width:3;`
5. Решение универсально - вы можете заменять в строке  `<path d="` путь
   на любой другой и получите фигуру с новой формой.

   **Картинка адаптивна - пробуйте изменять окно браузера.**

   ```html
   <svg version="1.1"
        baseProfile="full"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

       <defs>
     <mask id="cat">
    <g transform="scale(5)" >   
       <path d="M48.9 60.9 16.9 60.9 1.2 33.4 17.1 6.1 48.7 6.2 64.4 33.6z"
        style="fill:white; stroke-width:3;stroke:#dc143c"/>
       </g>
       </mask> 
      </defs>
         
    <image  x="-70" y="0" width="400" height="400" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkCUx.jpg" mask="url(#cat)">
    </image> 
    </svg>
   ```

**Шестигранник с закругленными уголками**

Изменён только патч.

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

    <defs>
  <mask id="cat">
 <g transform="scale(5)" >   
    <path d="m43 60.9-20.2 0C17.5 61 16.7 60.6 14 56.3L3.9 38.1C1.6 33 1.5 32.9 4 28.5L14.8 10c0 0 1.3-2.4 2.6-3.1 1.4-0.8 4.6-0.7 4.6-0.7l21.1 0.1c6.1-0.1 5.5 0.7 8.1 4.4L61.6 28.6c1.9 4.3 2.5 4.8 0.4 9.3L51.9 55.7C49.5 61 48.5 60.9 43 60.9Z"
     style="fill:white;stroke-width:2;stroke:#dc143c"/>
    </g>
    </mask> 
   </defs>
      
 <image  x="-70" y="0" width="400px" height="400px" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkCUx.jpg" mask="url(#cat)">
 </image> 
 </svg>
```

Comment: углы не закруглены

Comment: @Grundy это не проблема, сейчас сделаю

Comment: картинка адаптивна: не вмещается в экран, что в свернутом виде, что в развернутом :-D

Comment: @ Grandy и это не проблема

Comment: Спасибо за отличный ответ. Больше всего волнует вопрос - как накрутить сюда тень по маске. Ведь без тени можно вставить и простой картинкой png.

Answer (score 7):

**Вариант на чистом CSS**

Эх, столько усилий и все зря. Не могу в шестигранник вставить контент, хотя бы фоновую картинку что ли. Может кто допилит, обидно удалять. Но что-то мне кажется что это совсем уже не просто... (

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  /* height of hexagon */
  --hexagon-height: 150px;
  /* size of border */
  --hexagon-bordersize: 5px;
  /* size of border-radius */
  --hexagon-borderradius: 16px;
  /* width = height * sqrt(3) - 30% value of border-radius size */
  --hexagon-width: calc(var(--hexagon-height) * 1.7320508 - var(--hexagon-borderradius)*.3);
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  width: var(--hexagon-width);
  height: calc(2*var(--hexagon-height));
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hexagon,
.hexagon::after,
.hexagon::before {
  border: var(--hexagon-bordersize) solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: var(--hexagon-width);
  height: var(--hexagon-height);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(.5*var(--hexagon-height));
  border-radius: var(--hexagon-borderradius);
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.hexagon::after,
.hexagon::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(-1*var(--hexagon-bordersize));
  top: calc(-1*var(--hexagon-bordersize));
  height: calc(100% + 2*var(--hexagon-bordersize));
  /* + dubble size of border*/
}

.hexagon::after {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hexagon::before {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.shadow,
.shadow::after,
.shadow::before {
  background-color: black;
}

.shadow {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: .2;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hexagon"></div>
  <div class="hexagon shadow"></div>
</div>
```

**UPD 11.04.2020:** Вот полностью рабочий вариант

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  /* height of hexagon */
  --hexagon-height: 150px;
  /* size of border */
  --hexagon-bordersize: 5px;
  /* size of border-radius */
  --hexagon-borderradius: 16px;
  /* width = height * sqrt(3) - 30% value of border-radius size */
  --hexagon-width: calc(var(--hexagon-height) * 1.7320508 - var(--hexagon-borderradius)*.3);
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  width: var(--hexagon-width);
  height: calc(2*var(--hexagon-height));
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hexagon-bg {
  position: position;
  z-index: -10;
  width: var(--hexagon-width);
  height: calc(2*var(--hexagon-height));
  transform: scale(.97);
  background-image: url(https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2019/2-nature.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 1%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 99%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}

.hexagon,
.hexagon::after,
.hexagon::before {
  border: var(--hexagon-bordersize) solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: var(--hexagon-width);
  height: var(--hexagon-height);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(.5*var(--hexagon-height));
  border-radius: var(--hexagon-borderradius);
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.hexagon::after,
.hexagon::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(-1*var(--hexagon-bordersize));
  top: calc(-1*var(--hexagon-bordersize));
  height: calc(100% + 2*var(--hexagon-bordersize));
  /* + dubble size of border*/
}

.hexagon::after {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hexagon::before {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.shadow,
.shadow::after,
.shadow::before {
  background-color: black;
}

.shadow {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: .2;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hexagon"></div>
  <div class="hexagon shadow"></div>
  <div class="hexagon-bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ. Это сильно лучше того, что я нашел с css. Все вынесено в переменные. Но есть минус - css variables не работеют в edge, IE. Слишком большая несовместимость для простой картинки.
https://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20Variables

Comment: @AnatolyBabin в принципе переменные тут особо не нужны, я просто хотел акцентировать внимание на расчетах размеров необходимых для построения фигуры с учетом границ и скруглений, чтобы было понятно, что размеры это не некие магические подогнанные цифры. но к сожалению само решение тупиковое на мой взгляд.

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov мне пригодилось данное решение, что бы щас заново не учить всю геометрию, интересно откуда взялись такие цифры, особенно 1.7320508

Comment: @rodigy, это квадратный корень из 3. Характеризует соотношение полной высоты шестиугольника к его полной ширине.

Answer (score 5):

### Анимация шестиугольника

Несколько видов  анимаций при наведении курсора на фигуру:

Анимация бордюра шестиугольника  с использованием атрибута stroke-dashoffset:

```
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="img1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" dur="3s" values="186;0" > </animate>
```

Анимация увеличения прозрачности:

```
 <animate id="opc" attributeName="opacity" begin="img1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" dur="3s" values="0.1;1" fill="freeze" />
```

Возврат в исходное состояние:

```
<set attributeName="opacity" begin="opc.end+1.5s" to="0.2" />
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

    <defs>
  <mask id="cat">
 <g transform="scale(5)" >   
    <path id="path1" d="m43 60.9-20.2 0C17.5 61 16.7 60.6 14 56.3L3.9 38.1C1.6 33 1.5 32.9 4 28.5L14.8 10c0 0 1.3-2.4 2.6-3.1 1.4-0.8 4.6-0.7 4.6-0.7l21.1 0.1c6.1-0.1 5.5 0.7 8.1 4.4L61.6 28.6c1.9 4.3 2.5 4.8 0.4 9.3L51.9 55.7C49.5 61 48.5 60.9 43 60.9Z"
     style="fill:white;stroke-width:2;stroke:#dc143c; stroke-dasharray:186; stroke-dashoffset:0; fill:freeze;">
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="img1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" dur="3s" values="186;0" > </animate>

 </path> 
    </g>
    </mask> 
   </defs>
      
 <image id="img1"  x="-70" y="0" width="400px" height="400px" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkCUx.jpg" mask="url(#cat)" opacity="0.1">
 <animate id="opc" attributeName="opacity" begin="img1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" dur="3s" values="0.1;1" fill="freeze" />
 <set attributeName="opacity" begin="opc.end+1.5s" to="0.2" />
 </image> 
 </svg>
```

**Вращение  шестиугольника**

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

    <defs>
  <mask id="cat">
 <g transform="scale(5)" >   
    <path id="path1" d="m43 60.9-20.2 0C17.5 61 16.7 60.6 14 56.3L3.9 38.1C1.6 33 1.5 32.9 4 28.5L14.8 10c0 0 1.3-2.4 2.6-3.1 1.4-0.8 4.6-0.7 4.6-0.7l21.1 0.1c6.1-0.1 5.5 0.7 8.1 4.4L61.6 28.6c1.9 4.3 2.5 4.8 0.4 9.3L51.9 55.7C49.5 61 48.5 60.9 43 60.9Z"     style="fill:white;stroke-width:2;stroke:#dc143c;  fill:freeze;">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
     type="rotate"
     from="0 32.9 33.19" to="360 32.9 33.19"
      begin="img1.mouseover" dur="2s"
      end="img1.mouseout"
     repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"
   />
 </path> 
    </g>
    </mask> 
   </defs>
  
 <image id="img1"  x="0" y="0" width="400px" height="400px" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkCUx.jpg" mask="url(#cat)">
 
 </image> 
 </svg>
```

**Вращение и одновременное увеличение шестиугольника**

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="160" height="200" viewBox ="-10 -10 160 200" version="1.1">
  <g>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
     type="scale"
     values="1;1.5; 2;1.5; 1"
      begin="pr.mouseover" dur="8s"
      end="pr.mouseout"
     repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"
   />
   <circle cx="32.9" cy="33.19" r="32" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="12,4" fill="yellow"/> 
    
   <g>
   
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
     type="rotate"
     from="0 32.9 33.19" to="360 32.9 33.19"
      begin="pr.mouseover" dur="2s"
      end="pr.mouseout"
     repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"
   />
    <path id="pr" d="M48.5 60.9 16.9 60.8 1.2 33.4 17.1 6.1 48.7 6.2 64.4 33.6z" 
   style="fill:crimson;stroke-width:2; stroke:black;"/>
         
   </g>
   <circle cx="32.9" cy="33.19" r="27" stroke="yellow" stroke-dasharray="3,2"  fill="none"/> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю в качестве тени использовать второй `path` и сдвинуть его вправо и вниз относительно картинки с помощью команды: `translate(5 2.5)`
Цвет тени устанавливается либо здесь :

```
.boxShadow {
     fill:#2A2A41;
```

Либо изменением атрибутов SVG градиента:

```
<linearGradient id="horiz"
            x1="0%" y1="0%" 
            x2="100%" y2="50%"
            spreadMethod="pad" >
            <stop offset="40%" stop-color="white"/> 
            <stop offset="85%" stop-color="#383838"/>

        </linearGradient>
```

Ниже пример

```html
<body>
 <style>
 svg path{
 fill:inherit;
 stroke:inherit;
 }
  .boxShadow {
     fill:none;
  stroke:none;
  
}


  </style>  
 <div  class="container">
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

    <defs>
  <mask id="cat">
 <g transform="scale(5)" >   
    <path d="m43 60.9-20.2 0C17.5 61 16.7 60.6 14 56.3L3.9 38.1C1.6 33 1.5 32.9 4 28.5L14.8 10c0 0 1.3-2.4 2.6-3.1 1.4-0.8 4.6-0.7 4.6-0.7l21.1 0.1c6.1-0.1 5.5 0.7 8.1 4.4L61.6 28.6c1.9 4.3 2.5 4.8 0.4 9.3L51.9 55.7C49.5 61 48.5 60.9 43 60.9Z"
     style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white"/>
    </g>
    </mask> 
 <linearGradient id="horiz"
   x1="0%" y1="0%" 
   x2="100%" y2="50%"
   spreadMethod="pad" >
   <stop offset="40%" stop-color="white"/> 
   <stop offset="85%" stop-color="#383838"/>
   
  </linearGradient>
   </defs>
 
<g class="boxShadow" transform="scale(5.0) translate(5 2.5)" >   
      <path d="M42.4 60.9 22.5 60.9C17.3 61 16.5 60.6 13.9 56.3L3.9 38.1C1.6 33 1.5 32.9 4 28.5L14.6 10c0 0 1.3-2.4 2.6-3.1 1.4-0.8 4.5-0.7 4.5-0.7L39.6 6c2.6 0 6.1-0.1 6.9 0.5 1.4 1 3 4.2 3.8 5.2l9.7 16.6c0.9 2.2 1.6 3.4 1.7 4.6 0.1 1.2-0.2 2.5-1.3 4.7l-11.5 20.4c-2.8 3.2-4.4 2.8-6.7 2.8z" style="fill:url(#horiz);" /> 
    </g>
 <image x="-70" y="0" width="400px" height="400px" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkCUx.jpg" mask="url(#cat)">
 </image> 
 </svg>
 </div>
</body>
```

**Второй вариант**

Для формирования тени, придающей фигуре 3D эффект используется заполнение (fiil) и строка :

```
.boxShadow {
    stroke-width:2;
    stroke:grey;
   fill:#00174D;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <style>
 svg path{
 fill:inherit;
 stroke:inherit;
 }
  .boxShadow {
    stroke-width:2;
 stroke:grey;
   fill:#00174D;
   
}
  </style>  
 <div  class="container">
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

    <defs>
  <mask id="cat">
 <g transform="scale(5)" >   
    <path d="m43 60.9-20.2 0C17.5 61 16.7 60.6 14 56.3L3.9 38.1C1.6 33 1.5 32.9 4 28.5L14.8 10c0 0 1.3-2.4 2.6-3.1 1.4-0.8 4.6-0.7 4.6-0.7l21.1 0.1c6.1-0.1 5.5 0.7 8.1 4.4L61.6 28.6c1.9 4.3 2.5 4.8 0.4 9.3L51.9 55.7C49.5 61 48.5 60.9 43 60.9Z"
     style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white"/>
    </g>
    </mask> 
   </defs>
 
<g class="boxShadow" transform="scale(5.0) translate(5 2.5)">   
      <path d="m42.3 60.8-19.8 0.1c-5.2 0.1-6-0.3-8.7-4.6L3.9 38.1C1.6 33 1.5 32.9 4 28.5L14.6 10c0 0 1.3-2.4 2.6-3.1 1.4-0.8 4.5-0.7 4.5-0.7L39.6 6c2.6 0 6.1-0.1 6.9 0.5 1.4 1 3 4.2 3.8 5.2l9.7 16.6c0.9 2.2 1.6 3.4 1.7 4.6 0.1 1.2-0.2 2.5-1.3 4.7l-11.5 20.4c-2.8 3.5-4.8 2.5-6.7 2.7z" /> 
    </g>
 <image x="-70" y="0" width="400px" height="400px" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkCUx.jpg" mask="url(#cat)">
 </image> 
 </svg>
 </div>
</body>
```

Все примеры адаптивны. Чтобы регулировать начальный размер шестиугольника необходимо указать ширину и высоту контейнера SVG в процентах:

```
.container{width:30%; height:30%;}
```

```html
<body>
 <style>
 svg path{
 fill:inherit;
 stroke:inherit;
 }
  .boxShadow {
    stroke-width:2;
 stroke:grey;
   fill:#00174D;
   
}
.container{width:30%; height:30%;}
  </style>  
 <div  class="container">
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

    <defs>
  <mask id="cat">
 <g transform="scale(5)" >   
    <path d="m43 60.9-20.2 0C17.5 61 16.7 60.6 14 56.3L3.9 38.1C1.6 33 1.5 32.9 4 28.5L14.8 10c0 0 1.3-2.4 2.6-3.1 1.4-0.8 4.6-0.7 4.6-0.7l21.1 0.1c6.1-0.1 5.5 0.7 8.1 4.4L61.6 28.6c1.9 4.3 2.5 4.8 0.4 9.3L51.9 55.7C49.5 61 48.5 60.9 43 60.9Z"
     style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white"/>
    </g>
    </mask> 
   </defs>
 
<g class="boxShadow" transform="scale(5.0) translate(5 2.5)">   
      <path d="m42.3 60.8-19.8 0.1c-5.2 0.1-6-0.3-8.7-4.6L3.9 38.1C1.6 33 1.5 32.9 4 28.5L14.6 10c0 0 1.3-2.4 2.6-3.1 1.4-0.8 4.5-0.7 4.5-0.7L39.6 6c2.6 0 6.1-0.1 6.9 0.5 1.4 1 3 4.2 3.8 5.2l9.7 16.6c0.9 2.2 1.6 3.4 1.7 4.6 0.1 1.2-0.2 2.5-1.3 4.7l-11.5 20.4c-2.8 3.5-4.8 2.5-6.7 2.7z" /> 
    </g>
 <image x="-70" y="0" width="400px" height="400px" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkCUx.jpg" mask="url(#cat)">
 </image> 
 </svg>
 </div>
</body>
```